# Unable to start Docker Container in Windows 10

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am using Windows 10 pro and successfully installed Docker Client 18.09.0 and fetched hello-world docker image.

But when I try to run the image in container using docker run, it is giving the below error

```
C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: CreateComputeSystem 7b206637bedeb11c5f4bb8a5c12f941da3980a5c0e6e18d823f3323b6640a9de: The virtual machine could not be started because a required feature is not installed.
(extra info: {"SystemType":"Container","Name":"7b206637bedeb11c5f4bb8a5c12f941da3980a5c0e6e18d823f3323b6640a9de","Owner":"docker","IgnoreFlushesDuringBoot":true,"LayerFolderPath":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\7b206637bedeb11c5f4bb8a5c12f941da3980a5c0e6e18d823f3323b6640a9de","Layers":[{"ID":"ba045b84-94ef-5e96-a203-a8ef5cf53b41","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\2cbe39538cedc860f14e954ceed1044a5760df8830e8dc21bcbd4d21e88bf8f3"},{"ID":"959d85fc-a8bf-595a-84f9-a083080f2e27","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\3fc0987aeffab6be6b2bb0626867739cbad8dd80f42951e4e803b1e61b64543f"},{"ID":"40a5cfc0-ad6b-5b5e-85ff-dcd5826f380a","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\3e839c40c3c413a579f0f60a6ad8ec03daa496dcb61cfc621c35788beb6ae0d4"},{"ID":"be5e886a-ec0d-50e8-a735-c2c9a8b717de","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\12eddd7dc5f665f34ffebe1ff1600de14da8d7998950b9a3a180407b2781993a"}],"HostName":"7b206637bede","HvPartition":true,"EndpointList":["3C0F3EDA-3D0F-4C93-8908-C4DCB4FF6C8E"],"HvRuntime":{"ImagePath":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\3e839c40c3c413a579f0f60a6ad8ec03daa496dcb61cfc621c35788beb6ae0d4\\UtilityVM"},"AllowUnqualifiedDNSQuery":true}).
```

I am not sure what sure about the issue or what feature is not installed. When I searched the internet all the errors are about hyperv which is there in my environment. My docker info gives the below details by the way:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> docker info
Containers: 14
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 14
Images: 2
Server Version: 18.09.0
Storage Driver: windowsfilter
 Windows:
Logging Driver: json-file
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: ics l2bridge l2tunnel nat null overlay transparent
 Log: awslogs etwlogs fluentd gelf json-file local logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: inactive
Default Isolation: hyperv
Kernel Version: 10.0 17763 (17763.1.amd64fre.rs5_release.180914-1434)
Operating System: Windows 10 Pro Version 1809 (OS Build 17763.134)
OSType: windows
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 4
Total Memory: 23.54GiB
Name: DESKTOP-6MOD0L8
ID: 4QC3:QQKX:2BS2:P2JG:RUZA:3MK2:RAQ7:ZW7V:Q6YZ:5S56:Z3GQ:WXDC
Docker Root Dir: C:\ProgramData\Docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): true
 File Descriptors: -1
 Goroutines: 26
 System Time: 2018-12-10T12:14:05.5454663+05:30
 EventsListeners: 1
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Labels:
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
Product License: Community Engine
```

Comment: The docker setup at times does not identify the installed apps. Did you restart your host machine post the docker installation?

Comment: Yes. I did have restarted multiple times. Still the same

Comment: Did you ensure the Windows Containers and Hyper-V windows features are installed?

Comment: @James Blake Yeah Checked. But no help !!

Answer (score 3):

Just in case someone is using a Windows 10 Virtual Machine like me you can use the following command in power shell.

```
Set-VMProcessor -VMName my_virtual_machine -ExposeVirtualizationExtensions $true
```

Remember to run as Administrator before executing the command else it will give you an error saying you don't have permissions.

Comment: Does this command get entered into the host or the guest?

Answer (score 3):

This helped me with the same problem (I have virtualization enabled, but you can double-check on the Task Manager -> Performance tab):

1. Uninstall hyper-v (found in Windows Features)
2. Restart PC
3. Install hyper-v
4. Restart PC

Now you hopefully can build your container.

Source: https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/2956#issuecomment-514572084

Answer (score 0):

If you're running Docker with Hyper-V you may need to go into your BIOS and enable virtualization

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/canitpro/2015/09/08/step-by-step-enabling-hyper-v-for-use-on-windows-10/

I ran into this error with a recent Docker for Windows install and that was the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to run [RavenDB docker container](https://hub.docker.com/r/ravendb/ravendb/) in Windows 10. My Windows 10 is a virtual machine running in Parallels Desktop on Mac OS.

To be able to run it I had to enable the **Nested Virtualization** feature on Parallels:

[Nested Hyper-V support in Parallels Desktop virtual machines](https://kb.parallels.com/116239)

[image]

Having that disabled was causing the RavenDB container to not start with that generic message:

> "the virtual machine could not be started because a required feature is
> not installed."

By the way, to get the log while starting docker on the command line you can do this:

```
docker run -it ravendb/ravendb:windows-nanoserver-latest > C:/Temp/docker-log.txt 2>&1d
```

This may help you debug what's causing the issue...

Answer (score -5):

Try the following:

- Uninstall docker, reboot
- Uncheck Hyper-V and Windows Container in Windows Features, reboot
- [Completely remove docker](https://success.docker.com/article/how-to-completely-remove-docker-in-windows-10), reboot
- Re-install docker, maybe try [edge](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/edge-release-notes/)